# Focus на p и h.

Tags: jquery

Как пробегая по странице клавишей Tab, в фокус попадали не только (input, a ...) но и (p и h) ?

Answer (score 1):

http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/tabindex.
В хроме получилось то, что вы хотите. В других браузерах не смотрел.

```
<body>
  <a href="w" tabindex=1>Link</a>
  <p tabindex=2>Pa</p>
</body>
```